# Converting special characters from Javascript to Java

Tags: javascript, special-characters, windows-1252

I have a text area in my form which accepts all possible characters from user. i restrict the character count entered in the textarea to 10 . When the user enters a text with special character say `SampleTxt’ the character count in textarea is 10. But when i get the value of text area in the form, the text becomes ‘SampleTxt’

and the count of the text becomes 21. How to over come this issue?

```
function toCount(in) {
    var inObj=document.getElementById(in);
    var re='/\r\n|\n|\r\|\f/g';
    var i=0;
    while(re.match(inObj.value)){i++;}
    var length=characters - (inObj.value.length+i);
    if(length <= 0) {
        inObj.value=inObj.value.substr(0,characters);
document.getElementById("remcount").innerHTML = inObj.value.length;
        }
    }
```

Jsp

```
< html:textarea property="descTxt" styleId="desc" onkeyup="toCount('desc');" />
```

Comment: I think the answer to this question will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript

Comment: @aroth even when i use unescape. i get this problem

Comment: Yes, because `unescape()` is the wrong function to use in this case.  You need to use the `htmlDecode()` function described in the answer to the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like maybe you are getting the text of the textarea with `o.innerHTML` when you should be getting the text with `o.value`.

Post your actual code for more detailed help.

Comment: i am getting the value of the textarea by using var txt = escape(document.getElementById("desc").value);